# Facebook API unable to detect "user_location"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am requesting for read permission for [image: user location].

But when user clicks on log in with facebook, i am unable to see "your current city" in [image: logIn Permissions]

While running graph api, i am able to receive name, locale and email but not location. Please help.

API call: `private void getFBDetails() 
{       GraphRequestrequest=GraphRequest.NewMeRequest(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken, this); Bundle parameters = new Bundle(); parameters.PutString("fields", "id,name,location,locale,email"); request.Parameters = parameters; request.ExecuteAsync(); }`

Comment: so where is your api call? that would be the most important information.

Comment: `private void getFBDetails()
{
GraphRequestrequest=GraphRequest.NewMeRequest(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken, this);

   Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
   parameters.PutString("fields", "id,name,location,locale,email");
   request.Parameters = parameters;
   request.ExecuteAsync();
}` @luschn This is what are you refering to?

Comment: you should not post code in comments, especially when it´s relevant to the question. better edit your question.

Comment: either way, it is possible that the user did not even add a location. it´s more or less a text field.

Comment: @luschn Thanks for the revert. I am currently testing on my testing account and that has every single detail that is needed.

Comment: what do you mean with "testing account"? is it a fake user on facebook? or did you create a test user in the app? because the first one is not allowed, but would explain why you don´t see the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Most permissions need to go through a review process before they work for every user. Without review, permissions only work for users with a role in the App. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) is all you need to know about that.

The **email** permission does not need to get reviewed, that´s why it shows up.

Comment: Thanks @luschn For the review should put in the application with usage of country or no usage of country ?

Comment: no clue what you mean. just read the docs, everything you need to know about login review is in there. you can also just open the rewiew tab in the app settings, it´s pretty clear what you need to do there.